# blender game engine as simulation tool how to include one time calculations

Tags: python, blender

I want to use the blender game engine as a simulation tool for an UAV. I have four points where the UAV should fly to the closest point of the stretched area. Does anyone know how I can include those calculations in a script which runs every few frames. I tried sth like:

```
def init:

  if not 'init' in own:
    own['init'] = 1
    do all the path calculations
```

but then of course python does not know the values in other functions ...
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [two ways to run python code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13964) in the game engine, as a script or as a module. A script gets run from start to end while a module is a collection of functions that are called specifically. Modules can also keep global variables that can be accessed from any function.

To use a module, name the text block ending with `.py`, in the python controller select module and enter`mytextblock.myfunc`. The functions called by the controller should take one argument, which will be the controller object calling the function.

```
import bge

var1 = 1

def myfunc(cont):
    global var1
    var1 += 1
    update()

def update():
    global var1
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    scene.objects['Text']['Text'] = str(var1)
```

Comment: so the myfunc() is called once and the update() will do the movement?

Comment: `myfunc()` is called by the python controller based on the sensor triggering it, it is up to you whether `myfunc` does everything or calls other functions to do all or part of the work.

Comment: ok I see, well, actually I want to press a button for once then the full movement should be executed based on the calculations and when the object is at the right position the next script is called without me doing anything more. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Look at the near sensor. I'm thinking to position a 'destination' object based on your calculations then have a near sensor trigger the next script to reposition the destination.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. It works now. So now I'm trying to connect the near sensor to an Empty and then trigger the next destination calculations. Is that even possible with an Empty? Because nothing happens ... well actually it updates the Empty's position when the "game" finished ...

Comment: Should work either way, but I would think the plane gets the near sensor which runs the script that also re-positions the empty, the empty just marks a location that triggers the script.